# Storing a password hash in a session key

Tags: security, session, hash, passwords

I came across a situation where I need to store a hashed password in a session key. The password got hashed via bcrypt.

Is it safe to store a hashed password in a session key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on where the session data is stored and who has access to that storage.

By default, [PHP stores session data in files](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) that [might be readable by other users on the server](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path). So if you’re on a shared server, chances are that other users have also access to your session files. And as the session data is basically just a serialized form of the `$_SESSION` array, anyone with access to the physical session files would be able to read and/or write session data.